# I cant open my iPad mini!

Tags: ios, ipad, crash

While I was playing minecraft pe, I was changing the skin and when I got to the camera roll there's a somehwat black glitch that rebooted my iPad. After waiting for my iPad to open it keeps rebooting without the loading screen. It keeps showing me the Apple logo... I waited for 2 hours for it to open, but nothing happens! I dont want all my videos, and pictures to be deleted... plss helpp

Comment: Do you have your iPad backed up?

Answer (score 1):

Connect your iPad to a Mac or PC using the iTunes application. Try to make a backup from there; if that worked, restore the iPad to factory defaults (that basically erases everything that's on it) and restore the backup you just made.

For the future: Make a backup regularly, or you **will** lose your data some day.